# Android CursorLoader with ListView issue

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have finally after several tutorials make my CursorLoader display in my ListView but I have some questions that I hope you guys can help me to solve.

1) my big problem was this:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==CUSTOMERS){     
        DB.open();
        return DB.leer();        
        }
    else
    {           
        return null;        
    }

}
```

as you can see this is from my Content Provider class, my problem was that I dont figure I need to OPEN my DB. 
when I put the code for open the DB works for me but then I dont know if I need to close here or it close after doing this:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1){  
    Uri uri = Contenido.CONTENT_URI;  
    return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);    
    }

/** A callback method, invoked after the requested content provider returned all the data */    
@Override    
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {        
    mAdapter.swapCursor(arg1);    
    }
@Override    
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {        
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);    
    }
```

should I put DB.close() on any place of this functions?
Or maybe below this:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

getSupport is on the OnCreate Bundle. I really don't understand if its necesary close the db that is open from the Cursor query.

Comment: and what is DB class? if it is class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` then: 1. use single instance of it in ContentProvider implementation(not static private field assigned in `onCreate`), 2. do not close it ... do not store SQliteDatabase class, every time you need a database class use `DB.getWritableDatabase()/getReadableDatabase()`

Comment: well thats an important advice, I tell you because in other post I figure that the solution for this case was open() the database but I dunno if is a good solution for this kind of process